# Exactness of sequence induced by $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\cdot)$.

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence, pushforward

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$
For this problem, we let $0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{i} B \xrightarrow{j}C\rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence of groups, and $G$ an abelian group. It's not too hard to see that this induces an exact sequence:
$$0\rightarrow\Hom(G,A)\xrightarrow{i_*}\Hom(G,B)\xrightarrow{j_*}\Hom(G,C)$$
But I am then tasked with showing that if $G$ is free abelian, $j_*$ is surjective. The question suggests to me that such a condition must be necessary, but I can't think how I can use it to form a proof. Here's what I've come up with so far:

Given $\psi\in\Hom(G,C)$, we seek to construct $\phi\in\Hom(G,B)$ such that $j_*(\phi)=\psi$, or equivalently $j(\phi(g))=\psi(g)\; \forall g\in G$. Since $j$ is surjective by exactness, there exists $b\in B$ such that $j(b)=\psi(g)\; \forall g \in G$. Can we define $\phi$ by $\phi(g)=b$ where $j(b)=\psi(g)$? $j$ is not necessarily injective, so this may not be well-defined. Can we use the free-ness of $G$ at this point? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: what is $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n, A)$ isomorphic to?

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Ah yes! I think this gives me the solution! I'm going to put it together in an answer

Comment: Btw $A,B,C$ should be assumed to be abelian as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$
So, using the fact that $G$ free abelian (with basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$) means we can think of $\psi\in\Hom(G,C)$ as $\psi:e_i\mapsto c_i$ for some $c_i\in C$, each of which has a $j$-preimage $b_i\in B$, so we can define $\phi\in\Hom(G,B)$ by $\phi:e_i \mapsto b_i$, then $j\circ \phi=\psi$ as required.

Comment: But the rank of $Hom(G,C)$ and $Hom(G,B)$ is the same, right? so it shouldn't matter?

Comment: So, your solution is almost correct, you only need to remove "$G\simeq\mathbb{Z}^n$" and "$\text{Hom}(G,H)\cong H^n$" lines which are meaningless (or not true) in infinite rank case. And just use the fact that $G$ has a free basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$.

Comment: ah yeah I see your point. I think it just helped me 'picture' the solution.